# "MissingMethodException was unhandled" when I call a function of a C++ dll in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Currently, I developp a project for Windows Mobile in C#. I want to call functions of a C++ DLL. For this, Il use "DLLIMPORT". However, when I call a function:

```
[DllImport("IASAPI.dll")]
public static extern int IASInitialize(int phContext);
...
IASInitialize(0);
```

I have the following error:

> "*MissingMethodException was unhandled*"

Then, when I look inside my DLL file (with the software "DLL Export Viewer"), the function "IASInitialize" exists:

```
unsigned long __cdecl ias::IASInitialize(void * *)
```

So, have you got an idea to call functions of this DLL?

Comment: Your method has a return type of `int` and sends an int. The native method returns a `long` and accepts a `void*`. They dont match

Comment: Looks like that function is exported by iassvcs.dll, not iasapi.dll.

Comment: Where can I find "iassvcs.dll" ?

Comment: The fact that you observe the `ias::` prefix means that the function is exported under its *mangled* name. I suppose, it must be something like `?IASInitialize@ias@@YAKPAPAX@Z`. The export viewer demangled it for you, but the fact remains that it cannot be found under the bare name `IASInitialize`. Add `extern "C"` to the function declaration in C++ to switch off name mangling. As a side note, unmanaged pointer types must be matched by `System.IntPtr` instead of `System.Int32` in managed code. `IntPtr` is specially provided to cope with different pointer sizes on x86 and x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error you are getting is that you are not handling an exception that is being thrown.  And as Yuval stated, the exception is that there is no method that matches the signature that you are calling with.  Make sure that the return type and the parameters match what you are trying to call.